# Autofac how to register a service with multiple names?

Tags: c#, service, autofac, named

Is there a way to register a service with multiple names?
I know I can register service with a name by using .Named() but this method does not accept Array only a single string item.
So how can I register my service with multiple names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the `Named` method more than one time when you register a type :

```
builder.RegisterType<XService>()
       .Named<IService>("a")
       .Named<IService>("b")
       .Named<IComponent>("a");
```

this way, this component will be resolved when you resolved a `IService` named *a* or named *b* or a `IComponent` named `a`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Named() multiple times in the same registration line?